# Generalizing the idea of ​a circle kissing the vertex of a parabola

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections

Recently, while using GeoGebra, I was able to generalize the idea of ​​a parabolic vertex-kissing circuit I have achieved a wonderful result, but I cannot prove it. If anyone can prove it, please do so

Let $P$ be a parabola whose focus is $F$, whose directory is $L$, whose vertex is $O$, and whose axis of symmetry is $D$. The distance between $F$ and $L$ is equal to $d$.

Let $Q$ be an ellipse whose center is $S∈D$, one of its peaks $O$, and $M$ be one of the two vertices of $Q$ that does not lie on $D$, and let $k=OS/MS$.

Let $g=OS/d$

The largest possible ellipse $Q$ that has the value $k$ such that it touches $P$ at only one point is the ellipse that makes $g=k²$.

Any positive real number can be chosen as the value of the number $k$

The circle kissing the vertex of the parabola is a special case when $k=1$

Is this result known in advance? If so, please provide references that include this result

This is a linguistic description of what I have achieved: I have created the largest ellipse of all the ellipses that has a certain fixed ratio between its diagonals, which lies within the parabola, and the vertex of the parabola is one of its peaks, and the axis of symmetry of the parabola is one of its axes of symmetry, so that the parabola and the ellipse do not  They have more than one point in common.
It is an ellipse whose ratio between the distance of its center and the vertex of the parabola and the distance between the focus and the index is equal to the square of the ratio between the two dimensions of the ellipse

This is a dynamic property observation drawing on GeoGebra. You can move $V$ to change the ratio $K$ and you can move $U$ to change the size of the ellipse while maintaining $K$. If you enlarge the ellipse enough then the points $H$ and $J$ will appear to intersect the ellipse with the parabola. We are interested in the case where  These two points are inseparable.
You can monitor the values in the algebra section and see what happens.  (This plot is formatted for $k>1$)

https://www.geogebra.org/m/qrfgxfz5

Comment: I don't understand what $d$ is, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: $d$ represents the distance between $F$ and $L$ @Intelligenti pauca

Comment: There seem to be some unstated assumptions, such as that $S$ is on the same side of the parabola as $F$. (If it is on the other side, the size of the ellipse is unlimited.) I think there is an assumption about $OS/OF$, too.

Comment: Then it is not clear to me how it can be at the same time $k=d^2$ and "any positive real number can be chosen as the value of the number ".

Comment: Suppose you choose K=2 Then there is an infinite number of ellipses that have k=2 It touches the vertex of the parabola and lies inside it, but it is the largest one in it so that it intersects the parabola at the vertex only An ellipse whose center is four times the distance between the focus and the directory @Intelligenti pauca

Comment: Oh, right, there is a percentage that I forgot to write in the text of the question. I have modified it now. I hope it became clear @Intelligentipauca

Comment: J'ai modifié la question maintenant, vous pouvez la consulter maintenant @Intelligentipauca Internet a été coupé hier et je n'ai pas pu terminer le travail

Comment: I find $k^2$ much easier to read than $k²$. You can get $k^2$ using the encoding `$k^2$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your finding is not new: the limiting "kissing" ellipse is such that its curvature $\kappa$ at vertex $O$ is the same as the curvature of the parabola at $O$.
In fact:
$$
\kappa_\text{ellipse}={SO\over SM^2},
\quad
\kappa_\text{parabola}={1\over d},
$$
where $d$ is the distance between focus and directrix of the parabola (note that $\kappa$ is in both cases the reciprocal of the latus rectum). Just multiply both curvatures by $SO$ to get your equality.

Comment: Yes indeed, it seems obvious, I don't know how I didn't think of it like that, thank you anyway